# Does AMQP java client cache queue contents from RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

**Problem:**

I have a producer and consumer client which reads and write to/from the queue (used the java AMQP library for Rabbit MQ).

Producer produces at a higher rate than the consumer.
Now, on stopping the Producer the consumer still continues to consumer the data from the queue.

But the queue shows empty on the Rabbit MQ console.

Does the client library cache the contents from the queue? Why is this behavior happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the client library cache the contents from the queue?

Yes, the client can cache the messages

> Why is this behavior happening?

In order to improve the performance.

BTW you can see the client [prefetch](http://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) parameter

**EDIT***

By default, messages are heavily prefetched. Messages are retrieved by the consumers in
blocks, but are actually consumed and removed from the queue when the consumers send
the ack.

You should check the unacknowledged messages:

[image]